# Outer Join and Inner Join

Tags: sql, duplicates, inner-join, outer-join

I used `inner join` and `outer join` the following query. When executing this query I get duplicate records. How can I get unique results?

```sql
Select * 
    From DeliveryOrderMaster
Inner Join DeliveryOrder ON DeliveryOrderMaster.VoucherNo = DeliveryOrder.DONo
Inner Join Customer ON DeliveryOrderMaster.Code = Customer.ar_code
Left Outer Join tblbatchSerialNos On DeliveryOrder.DoNo = tblbatchSerialNos.VoucherNo And DeliveryOrder.StockCode = tblbatchSerialNos.ProductCode 
Where DeliveryOrderMaster.VoucherNo= 'DO01304' 
ORDER BY DeliveryOrder.DoNo ASC,DeliveryOrder.ID ASC
```

Comment: You should pre-format the code first.

Comment: Spelling, attempt to save this poorly written question from oblivion

Answer (score 0):

The problem there arent inner or left join. The problem can be the type of table. Are you sure that you have used the correct key to Connect table? Can you give an example of wath return the query?